# How can I force a download of a pdf in a url?

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, download

I have a URL that goes to a pdf file. In my coldfusion page, I want to allow the user to download the file (using the open/save dialog or however that particular browser handles it).

This is the code I have so far:

```
<cfset tempFile = getTempFile(getTempDirectory(), 'testfile') />
<cfhttp url="myUrl/myFile.pdf" method="get" file="#tempFile#"/>

<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=myFile.pdf">
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="#tempFile#">
```

This seems to work... but when I try to open the file it tells me something's wrong with the file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `method="getAsBinary"`. You may need to supply both `file` and `path`.

Comment: @leigh - method="getAsBinary" throws an error... did you mean getAsBinary="yes"?

Comment: Yep. My bad. I went a little ADD there ;)

Comment: @leigh - tried it, didn't help... :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> file attribute: [Do not specify the path](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ffc.html) to the directory in this attribute; use
>   the path attribute.

Try separating the file name and path:

```
<!--- hard coded for clarity --->
<cfhttp url="http://www.somesite.com/path/testFile.pdf" 
        method="get" 
        getAsBinary="yes"
        path="c:/test/" 
        file="testFile.pdf"/>

<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=myFile.pdf" />
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="c:/test/testFile.pdf" />
```

For smaller files you might skip the temp file and use `<cfcontent variable..>`

```
<cfhttp url="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/documentation/en/coldfusion/mx7/cfmx7_cfml_qref.pdf" 
        method="get" 
        getAsBinary="yes" />

<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=myFile.pdf" />
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" variable="#cfhttp.fileContent#" />
```

---

**Update:**  Dynamic example using a temp file

```
<cfset tempDir  = getTempDirectory() />
<cfset tempFile = getFileFromPath(getTempFile(tempDir, "testfile")) />

<!--- uncomment to verify paths 
<cfoutput>
    tempDir = #tempDir#<br />
    tempFile = #tempFile#<br />
</cfoutput>
<cfabort />
--->
<cfhttp url="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/documentation/en/coldfusion/mx7/cfmx7_cfml_qref.pdf" 
        method="get" 
        getAsBinary="yes"
        path="#tempDir#" 
        file="#tempFile#" />

<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=myFile.pdf" />
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="#tempDir#/#tempFile#" />
```

Comment: Thanks! Separating the file name and path didn't help, but the second suggestion (using the variable) worked!

Comment: That is surprising. Both snippets worked for me under CF9. Just curious, what code did you use to separate the path?

Comment: I'm using CF8. I saved the `getTempDirectory()` into a variable instead of using it on the fly to get the temp file, so I had the path, and I separated the file name using something like `listLast(tempFile, '/')`

Comment: @froadie - Works perfectly for me. I do not think it is a version problem. Double check your variables. Make sure they are what you think they are ;) See update.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, your coding is fine in Google Chrome. In IE, error message prompt. It's because of "**file path**" cannot support for URL path. Should use directory path instead of URL path.

Comment: What do you mean by directory path and where?