# getting pdf with cfhttp throwing base64 error

Tags: coldfusion

hi i am calling a page with cfhttp to a pdf file

```
<cfhttp url="#pdfurl#" method="get" throwOnError="Yes" resolveurl="true" redirect="true">
    <cfhttpparam type="cookie" name="#st_cookieName#" value="#st_cookievalue#">
</cfhttp>
<cfset binary = toBinary(cfhttp.filecontent)>
<cfset tmpFile = getTempFile(getTempDirectory(),"pdf")>
<cfset fileWrite(tmpFile, binary)>
<cfheader name="Content-disposition" value="inline;filename=new.pdf" />
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="#tmpFile#" deletefile="no">
```

i am getting an error:

```
The parameter 1 of function ToBinary, which is now %PDF-1.4%âãÏÓ 9 0 obj<</Linearized 1/O 11/H [ 1576 228 ]/L 72394/E 71398/N 1/T 72171>>endobj xref9 590000000016 00000 n 0000001522 00000 n 0000001804 00000 n 0000002110 00000 n 0000002253 00000 n 0000002311 00000 n 0000002369 00000 n 0000004525 00000 n 0000004583 00000 n 0000004686 00000 n 0000004744 00000 n 0000004847 00000 n 0000005190 00000 n 0000005232 00000 n 0000005275 00000 n 0000005381 00000 n 0000005667 00000 n 0000006882 00000 n 0000007030 00000 n 0000007598 00000 n 0000007907 00000 n 0000008140 00000 n 0000011766 00000 n 0000011915 00000 n 0000012364 00000 n 0000012606 00000 n 0000012840 00000 n 0000015312 00000 n 0000015455 00000 n 0000016226 00000 n 0000016646 00000 n 0000016874 00000 n 0000022797 00000 n 0000044306 00000 n 0000046758 00000 n 0000047483 00000 n 0000047525 00000 n 0000047568 00000 n 0000047674 00000 n 0000047817 00000 n 0000048357 00000 n 0000048645 00000 n... must be a base-64 encoded string.
```

the pdf url is like this:

```
https://example.com/pdfs/file_102.89E-02.pdf
```

Here is the screen as i tried with method: `head`

[image]

Comment: Try getAsBinary="yes" in your cfhttp call.  You will not need to do the ToBinary() then.

Comment: You'll have to also add the file attribute to the cfhttp tag.  file="#tmpFile#"

Comment: You can also try `binaryDecode()` instead of `toBinary()`. Although I question why you are even doing this. If the PDF is already created and accessible, why not just give the user a link to the PDF?

Comment: If you look at the error message, and the dump, the response is obviously *not* a base64 string. It is returning binary.  Voting to close as a duplicate of [How can I force a download of a pdf in a url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835774/how-can-i-force-a-download-of-a-pdf-in-a-url/6836370#6836370) . Just change "attachment" to "inline"