# How to grab the file from the folder and show to the user? ColdFusion/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, excel, coldfusion

I have been working on the project where user should be able to click on the link and open excel file. My files are sitting on the server folder, I use JavaScript `onClick` function to open excel files. This way of opening files is very insecure because user can see direct link to the folder(if they open devTools). I would like to use ColdFusion function that will grab files from the folder and server them to the user. I was wondering what is the best way to do that in ColdFusion? Is there and functions that directly look in the folder and servers the file? Here is my current code:

```
 <cfdirectory directory="#exportsDir#" action="list" filter="*.xls" recurse="no" name="fileList">

<cfoutput query="fileList">
    <cfset href = "../Reports/#fileList.name#">

    <div onClick="location.href = '#href#';">#fileList.name#</div>
</cfoutput>
```

If anyone have suggestions on how to approach this problem please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: What you are looking for is similar to content disposition: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835774/how-can-i-force-a-download-of-a-pdf-in-a-url

Comment: You may also want to go serverside and be sure to disable directory browsing. This is especially easy in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid outputting the path to the file there are several ways to do so.

## URL rewrite

One is to use a URL rewriter. In Apache, for example, you can enable it via the [mod_rewrite module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). This looks then something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/files/"
RewriteRule "^(.+)$"  "../Reports/$1" [L]
```

## ColdFusion script

Another way is to let a ColdFusion script serve the file, so the path to it is hidden behind the script. See [How can I force a download of a pdf in a url?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6835774/432681)